# should one synchronize on a list itself or on a lock object?

Tags: java, synchronization, synchronized

For some time now a i have a question in my mind: how is it safer to sychronize the access to a list (ArrayList ...) when multiple threads have access to that list ? Is it safer to synchronize on the list itself or is it safer to create a lock object and use it to synchronize on it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is what you want. There can be 2 cases (eventually):

**You use a seperate lock to synchronize.**

```
someMethod(){
synchronized(lock){
// code to access/modify List here
}
}
```

**You synchronize on the List instance directly**

```
synchronized(list)
{
// code to access/modify list here
}
```

The first case is *safe* if `someMethod()` is the only way of accessing the list. Any other thread from a different flow can modify the actual list.

The second case locks the actual *list* instance, So, you are always guaranteed to have only one thread accessing/ modifying the list at a time.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - *yes*. Considering the fact that a *Happens-before* is not guaranteed *within* a synchronized block :)

Comment: Let's take the case of synchronizing on the list itself. Isn't there some corner case where some thread can modify the content of the list  and so i won't have the same list object when a second lock is going to be done ? Thanks

Comment: @JohnyX - No. Only one thread will be able to access *that List instance* at a time. You will be locking on the list instance. Any new object created/returned by another thread will not make other threds to lock on the new list object. They will still be locking on the same old list object.

Comment: I was watching a tutorial and they mentioned not to lock on list. What happens if somewhere down the line I did `list = new ArrayList<>()` or changing the reference? The video said the lock would then be lost if we changed the reference of list variable to something else. Do you know how this is the case? Like why would it be lost? I guess we will get a new HashCode and our list will be pointing to new hash while synchronized might be pointing to old hash?

Answer (score 5):

No need to synchronize on your own. Collections framework already did it. Just make use of that.

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(yourList);
```

And use the returned `list`. Remember that the method

> Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) list backed by the specified list.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I know about Collections.synchronizedList. I was not referring to that, just what is the best practice, the best choice of the two.

Comment: @JohnyX I usually synchronize the essential parts of class rather than whole Object as lock:)

Answer (score 1):

Both are equivalent in terms of safety, as long as your lock `Object` is `final`. It will probably be easier to lock on the `List` itself if it is being accessed on several class in your code, so you don't have to pass both the `List` and the `Object` you are synchronizing on.
 But you should avoid all of that and let Java handle synchronization for you by using `List<T> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<T>)`

Answer (score 0):

both options are more or less equivalent as long as you consistently lock your object. therefore synchronization on list itself is maybe more error-free since you can't accidentally use "the other object" for synchronization.

as mentioned before, you can use `syncList = Collections.synchronizedList(yourList)` if you require only "simple" synchronization... it would be the safest way, however it is not sufficient in more generic synchronization scenarios like "put-if-absent" etc. E.g. following snipped is **BAD** - is not synchronized enough:

```
if (syncList.contains(element)) { syncList.add(element); }
```